# ENC28J60 Custom board, heat and performance issues. need input

Tags: enc28j60

So since the last post I made regarding the differential line matching on a custom board [HERE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/330865/ethernet-to-spi-converter-differential-line-importance) I have finished the board and started using it. the enc28j60 chip works as expected and i get around 2.3 Mbps average up and download speed. My problem is chip got so hot that i could not touch it for longer then 3 seconds. I looked through the schematic again and can not find the issue. I then blindly started removing components, checking values trying to understand what is going on. I then got to the ferrite bead on the center tap of the RJ45 Jack.( see L1 in the schematic )

After completely removing L1 the heat was atleast 40% decreased while running but a side effect was that im now getting 12Mbps download speed and 14 Mbps upload speed (see image attached). Ever since I removed the L1 the Actively lights on the Magjack stopped working.

Can someone shed some light on what is happening here ?
[image]

Comment: Do you mean remove L1 altogether or replace it with a wire to 3.3V? I've used ENC28J60.. the chip gets very warm but not hot.. where did you get the 10uH value for the coil? Microchips schematic shows only ferrite, I think....

Comment: removed it completely. I have tried just adding a 100K to pull the line high but the chip does not work at all if it is added. I go that 10uh From other enc28 reference designs. but this still does not explain why the LEDs stopped working